# Default Workflow name be changed in Translation job detail page

Tags: web8.5, workflow, translation-manager

Web 8.5  Translation jobs detail - general page, the default workflow option will change to a different one after they submit to the next step. This is kind of strange, anyone ever see this error? see attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK - the default workflow can be defined in the TMS/world-server side? you can check what was defined there?

Comment: Thank you very much for reply. I will check it on WS/TMS side.